# Smoother slider movement in scrollbar pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qscrollarea

In my code, when one button is clicked, the slider (it is in QScrollArea) is automatically shifted with setSliderPosition(new position). But it happens very quickly and it makes your eyes uncomfortable.
How can I animate movement or make it with QTimer?
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: See the [QScroller](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscroller.html) documentation.